# Seeking clue for inequality proof

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I'm attempting to show that no variable $\lambda$ can satisfy both of the following inequalities:

1. $\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}+x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{d_2}-x_{1_2}} <\lambda$
2. $\lambda < \dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}$

where $x_{1_1}>x_{2_1}>x_{d_1}>0$ and $x_{2_2}>x_{d_2}>x_{1_2}>0$. To do so, I plan on proving that the LHS of the first inequality is greater than or equal to the RHS of the second inequality. Does anyone have a clue as to the best way to proceed? Things that I've noticed are that there is a constant expression in both numerators, and that the denominator of the LHS of the first inequality is smaller than the denominator of the RHS of the second inequality.

-------edit: I am aware that $x_{d_1}$ doesn't appear in either inequality. It is not a typo.

Comment: $x_{d_1}$ does not appear in 1. or 2. - is there a typo?

Comment: Sorry, there is a variable $x_{d_1}$ in the problem that I'm working on, but it's not part of the inequalities. I'll edit.

Comment: Are the $x$'s all positive? Otherwise it could be possible to find such an $\lambda$.

Comment: Just edited. The x's must be non-negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use that $x_{d_2}-x_{1_2}<x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}$ and therefore:
$$\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}+x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{d_2}-x_{1_2}} >
\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}+x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}=\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}+\frac{x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}.$$

Furthermore $\frac{x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}>0$ and hence

$$\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}+x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{d_2}-x_{1_2}} >
\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}+\frac{x_{d_2}+x_{2_2}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}}>\dfrac{x_{1_1}-x_{2_1}}{x_{2_2}-x_{1_2}} .$$